# Converting a quantity to a decimal form

Tags: number-representation

I have a function giving me this:

```
(5 Coulomb)/(6 Second)
```

as output.  I want this in decimal form and would like to have the variables taken off the end for unit analysis. How would I do this?  I have tried `NumberForm`, but I think that the unassigned variables I am using for units are throwing it off.

**EDIT:**  Here is what I have for code

```
In[1]: f[P_, V_] := P/V
In[2]: f[100 W, 120 V]
Out[2]:(5 Coulomb)/(6 Second)
```

I took your advice and put:

```
In[1]: f[P_, V_] := P/V
In[2]: f[100 W, 120 V]//N[#]&
```

And got:

```
Out[2]:(0.833333 Coulomb)/(Second)
```

Comment: `N[(5 coulomb)/(6 second)]` gives me `(0.833333 coulomb)/second`. You could add `/. {coulomb -> 1, second -> 1}` at the end to get rid of the `coulomb` and `second`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: When I do `Quantity[5, "Coulombs"]/Quantity[6, "Seconds"]`, then I don't get what you have. Could you make a small example and include code? More importantly, can you say what you mean by *variables*? I only see numbers and units..

Comment: You have asked the same exact question again only 8 min after this one: [How do I extract variables from an expression](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87667/27951). You should not spam the site with duplicate questions.

Comment: @MarcoB, read what I said in my post.  I asked two separate questions, one per post, which is what you are supposed to do on StackExchange sites.  One was about converting a number to decimal form and the other was about extracting units from an expression.

Answer (score 3):

To be a bit more systematic, I would suggest declaring the units you want to work with in a global variable, and then defining a function `unitsToUnity` that sets all of those units to unity as follows:

```
$myUnits = {Coulomb, Second};

unitsToUnity[expression_] := 
 expression /. Thread[$myUnits -> 1]

(5 Coulomb)/(6 Second) // unitsToUnity

(* ==> 5/6 *)
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unclear about what I was asking.  I got an answer to this in another question; what I was really asking here was how to make sure my output was in decimal format instead of being given as a fraction.  Rahul answered that for me in his comment above.