# How do I extract units from an expression

Tags: units

I need to take the units off of this expression:

(5 Coulomb)/(6 Second)

In order to do some unit simplification.  Is there any way to do this?  I have tried Case, but could not get it to work properly.  Because I cannot use these if they are put in a table, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression) is not helpful to me, so please do not mark this as duplicate; in order to be able to use them, I need them to remain one divided by the other.

**EDIT:**  This question was marked as duplicate.  Whoever did this misread my other question.  This one is about extracting units from an expression and the other is about expressing a fraction in decimal form.

Comment: Exact duplicate of your other question: [Converting a quantity to a decimal form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87665/converting-a-quantity-to-a-decimal-form)

Comment: No it's not.  Read what the question is about before marking it as duplicate.  If you had done this, you would not have marked this as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `QuantityMagnitude` and `QuantityUnit` are the functions you need. In your case,

```
a = Quantity[5, "Coulombs"]/Quantity[6, "Seconds"];
QuantityMagnitude[a]
```

Yields 5/6.
If you want the units, use

```
QuantityUnit[a]
```

Which yields Coulombs/Seconds

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverse of this?  I want to end up with Coulombs/Seconds.